# HTTPs port error on NodeJs and Express, why? banging my head on wall

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, https

Why do I get an error on my Amazon server when running my NodeJS app?

sudo node app.js

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE

at errnoException (net.js:904:11)

at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)

at listen (net.js:1064:10)

at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)

at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/www/app.js:65:38)

at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Here is my code:

```
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(4000, function() {
    console.log('Express HTTP server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(443, function() {
    console.log('Express HTTPS server listening on port 443');
});
```

I think the problem is the 443 because when I delete the https.createServer "listen()" connection then everything works fine.

Thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another process running that's using this port (probably another instance of your app.

Use `ps aux` to see your running processes.

Use `lsof -i | grep 4000` to see what's using this port.

Comment: Thanks @Erik, but the port 4000 is working fine, my problem is the 443 I think so because when I delete the https.createServer then it works fine

Comment: I get nothing when running that command ::(
1. $ lsof -i | grep 443
2. $ lsof -i | grep 4000
3. $

Comment: lsof -i would show you if another process is using that port. I'm guessing you're not root so you don't have permission on 443 (port 1-1024 are privileged)

Comment: DO you think maybe the second "listen(" is wrong?. I have admin privileges and I'm running "sudo node app.js"

Comment: Maybe you need a `var secure_server = ` in front of there? You're creating an object and then returning it to nowhere.